# Detecting key presses is not working in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make my first half GUI program, and i am using `tkinter`, but I cannot figure out why it is not working.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import os 
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

root = Tkinter.Tk()

#text

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "EASY hacktool for Linux\n\n1.john\n2.Crack wep\n3.Crack wpa/wpa2\n q to quit\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", )
text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "25.50")
text.tag_config("here", background="black", foreground="green")
text.pack()


def key(event):
    if event.keysym == 'q':
        root.destroy()
    elif event.keysym == '\x31':
        os.system("python Gui/john.py")
    elif event.keysym == '\x32':
        os.system("python Gui/aircrack.py")

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)


root.mainloop()
```

When I press the 1 (\x31), it works perfectly, but when I press the '2'(\x32), nothing happens, I have tried my `aircrack.py`, and it works, but this doesn't.

Comment: to access python code from other file, it would be more *idiomatic* to use `import gui.john; gui.john.foo`

Answer (score 0):

the code works fine for me if i replace

```
os.system("python Gui/aircrack.py")
```

with just some print statement...does it work for you?
what is your aircrack.py?Make sure it is in the same path.